# I think this question about formatting superimposed titles in a screenplay should be reopened

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

This question was closed as off-topic: [Multiple superimposed supers](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/49552/multiple-superimposed-supers)

The question asks about how to format multiple consecutive superimposed titles in a screenplay. [Screenplays are explicitly on topic for this site](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/937/are-questions-about-screenplay-on-topic), so I believe this question should not have been closed.

Can we please vote to reopen this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you. I'm not sure why the question was closed, and I'm definitely not sure why it was migrated to English.SE (who understandably rejected the migration because it's off-topic there). I think it *may* have been a little unclear what OP was asking for help with, but I've edited the question to clarify, and voted to reopen.

**UPDATE**: The question has now been re-opened by a Community Manager.